# Gnome 3 on OpenSUSE 12.2 Proxy Porblem

Tags: opensuse, gnome3, proxy, socks

Recently I've switched from Fedora 17 to OpenSUSE 12.2. I used to add my proxy from Network Settings>Network Proxy>Manual Method>Socks Hosts. But it doesn't work on openSUSE.

I get the following error in Chrome:

```
Error 120 (net::ERR_SOCKS_CONNECTION_FAILED): Unknown error.
```

Further more proxy setting at Gnome Config Editor is not applied at all.

I know that I can use proxy at software level (like firefox) but then I have to set the proxy for all of my application and some application doesn't support that.

Answer (score 1):

Go to 'Applications' tab at the right select 'System Tools' click on 'YaST' enter the root password and then you will find an icon 'proxy' click on it and complete the form.

Comment: unfortunately yast's proxy doesn't support socks, but it works great with http and https!